# Parse - Check for Update inside BeforeSave in Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to check that I am not saving a duplicate entry for the attend status of an event - so on BeforeSave I am checking that the event rsvp has not already been entered - if it has, I want to know if it needs to be updated. If it does, I want to do an update instead of create a new RSVP entry.

This is my code - I can't seem to get it to work, even with the simplist update inside BeforeSave.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Rsvps", function(request, response) {

var eventid = request.object.get("eventid");
var userid = request.object.get("userid");
var rsvp_status = request.object.get("rsvp_status");

var Rsvps = Parse.Object.extend("Rsvps");
var query = new Parse.Query(Rsvps);
query.equalTo("eventid", eventid);
query.equalTo("userid", userid);
query.first({
  success: function(object) {
    if (object) {
        // response.error("An RSVP for this event already exists.");
        request.object.id = object.id;
        request.object.set('rsvp_status', "attending");
        request.object.save();
    } else {
      response.success();
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});

});
```

I've tried so many variation of this without any joy - this my latest attempt.

Comment: have you tried using Parse.Cloud.define instead of Parse.Cloud.beforeSave

Comment: I tried initially to define a function, but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. My hope is that it generates a better error messages. It also prints numbers to the Parse.com logs so we can see how far the function progresses before it dies. -ahoffer

Comment: I added a check to prevent the unterminated recursion. Try the code now.

Comment: If the code works for you, would you accept the answer I provided?

Comment: Have a look at promises in Parse documentation. They can really make your code much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

@CityLogic you shouldn't have to call that second save in @ahoffer's example, because you are in the beforeSave trigger. Just set the resp_status and call response.success().

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED. I added a check not to not update an existing object if the 'attending' value is correct. Give this a try. If there are any you cannot resolve, add the errors as a comment to this answer.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Rsvps", function (request, response) {

    var eventid = request.object.get("eventid");
    var userid = request.object.get("userid");
    var rsvp_status = request.object.get("rsvp_status");

    //Do not re-declare the class
    //var Rsvps = Parse.Object.extend("Rsvps");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Rsvps");

    //Check for existing RSVP
    query.equalTo("eventid", eventid);
    query.equalTo("userid", userid);

    query.first().then(function (object) {

            if (object && object.get('rsvp_status') != "attending") {
                //RSVP exists and needs updating.
                // Do not save the object attached to the request.
                //Instead, update existing object.

                object.set('rsvp_status', "attending");
                object.save().then(function () {
                        response.error('Updated existing RSVP to "attending"');
                    },

                    function (error) {

                        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    });

            } else {

                //Continuing and save the new RSVP object because it is not a duplicate.
                response.success();
            }
        },
        function (error) {

            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

        });
});
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:E2014-01-31T15:35:56.065Z] v52: before_save triggered for Rsvps for user t6CspxQuhm
  Input: {"original":{"eid":XXXX,"rsvp_status":"not_replied","start_time":"2014-01-30T20:30:00+0200","uid":XXXXXX,"createdAt":"2014-01-31T15:34:14.985Z","updatedAt":"2014-01-31T15:34:14.985Z","objectId":"NbTU5L89TV"},"update":{"rsvp_status":"attending"}}
  Result: success/error was not called

Comment: Adding a new one works, updating an existing one fails with: 
`Error: Error: 142 Error: 142 Error: 142 Error: 142 Error: 124 Too many recursive calls into Cloud Code` - I'm guessing that the save() triggers a beforeSave and so on, etc...  I had some feedback on this from Parse.com [https://www.parse.com/questions/do-an-update-inside-beforesave-in-cloud-code ] and it looks like, as you suggested, a defined function is the way to go.

Comment: I know this is old, but instead of calling save on the updated object you can pass that object to the response like: response.success(object).  This returns the object that you have found to already exist, which you subsequently updated.  By passing it as a parameter to the response the updated object will be saved instead.  Reference: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.BeforeSaveResponse.html